# pywin32 captive installation (avoid py*.dll getting installed in system32 directory)

Tags: python, pywin32, python-embedding

I have python as an embedded scripting environment in my application. I supply the python bits (python26.dll, DLLs & Lib folders) with my application. All this to avoid asking users to install python (you know how it goes in big corporations).

All works nice except pywin32. It installs pythoncom26.dll and pywintypes26.dll to the **system32** directory. I want to keep these dlls in my Python directory. One option is to add my Python directory to the PATH env variable. But would like to avoid it for obvious reasons (windows DLL search path priorities issues).

Is there a way to tell Windows (a windows API is also fine) to look at my directories to load these pywin32 dlls? From what I understand these dlls get called by Windows COM.

Thanks.

Edit1:
Note that python is deployed embedded with my application.

Comment: Why not freeze (http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) your script into an executable, thereby bypassing all the dll hacking you seem to need?

Comment: No. My application is not python scripts. Its a GUI application with its own exe & dlls. Python allows customization and acts as a glue between this C++ application & excel via pywin32.

Comment: Why is that a problem... can't you write all the Python scripts that you need as glue beforehand, `cx_freeze` them all for distribution, and call the resulting executables as and when you need them? For instance, suppose you have a Python script that saves the current `foo` to a spreadsheet, called say `spreadsheeter.py`. Then freeze that into `spreadsheeter.exe` and call *that* whenever you want to save to Excel.

Comment: Note that python is deployed embedded with my application. I want to just provide the platform. Customers are supposed to write the python scripts for their word & excel needs.

Answer (score 0):

I previously used `py2exe` to freeze the application and all the DLLs. Then use `Innosetup` to create an installer. Work like a charm.

Comment: No. My application is not python scripts but an exe (gui application)

Comment: I don't think this should be an issue. Maybe you need add stub as an entry point to py2exe. It just finds all the script and binary dependency and put them together so that you that can distribute it.